# Custom Groovy library - println not printing to console

Tags: groovy, console, println

I've written a custom Selenium library in Groovy. In the library, I have a method that handles exceptions.

```
void throwException(GroovyException error) throws GroovyException {
        
        println("Exact details of this error are below:")
        println(error.toString())
        throw error
        
    }
```

This library gets used by my Groovy Unit Tests, which contain Selenium code. When I run my tests, even after an error, nothing gets printed to the console. I've debugged everything to make sure that this method is being called when there's an exception. It's as if the println is being swallowed by something.

I would appreciate any help in trying to get messages printed to the console. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: `println` doesn't necessarily write to the console.  `println` writes to wherever `stdout` is pointing.  That is a good thing to investigate.

Comment: Is there a reason why stdout wouldn't be pointed to the console? How do I edit where stdout is pointing to? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Is there a reason why stdout wouldn't be pointed to the console?" - Yes.  For example, testing frameworks often redirect stdout to a generated report.

Comment: "How do I edit where stdout is pointing to?" - That depends on how the process is being started.  Are you running an executable jar?

Comment: The library I'm using is in a jar which I import into my JUnit Groovy test using "import". I execute the JUnit test by right clicking it in Eclipse, going to "Run As" and then JUnit test.

Comment: "I execute the JUnit test by right clicking it in Eclipse, going to "Run As" and then JUnit test." - If it is a JUnit test, by default JUnit will redirect stdout.  I am unfamiliar with modern Eclipse but I am certain the IDE provides a mechanism for viewing that.

Comment: I think your real question is something like, how to view what is written to stdout when running a JUnit test from Eclipse using the technique you described.

Comment: If I put the println() in the JUnit test itself, it prints to the console just fine. But if the println() is in the library, nothing gets printed.

Comment: try `System.out.println` instead of `println`

Comment: "If I put the println() in the JUnit test itself, it prints to the console just fine. But if the println() is in the library, nothing gets printed. " - That is very surprising behavior.  I am sorry that I can't help.  Best of luck.

Comment: @daggett Tried, but to no effect. I honestly think something is just swallowing the println commands.

Comment: selenium itself or drivers could intercept out and redirect it to some log file: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging